# Is downloading or using proprietary software off bittorrent sites illegal?

Tags: copyright, software

If someone downloads software, that normally requires paying money to buy, from a P2P file sharing program is it illegal to

1. download it?
2. install it?
3. use it?

I'm not talking about normally freely available software, like Firefox or whatever.

Comment: You may have fun reading this though: [How is it possible for millions to use pirated software at home and never get arrested?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2163/how-is-it-possible-for-millions-to-use-pirated-software-at-home-and-never-get-ar)

Comment: Why do you think that the distribution method (p2p) makes using illegal software somehow legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes

They are all copyright violations.

Comment: What about uploading them?

Comment: That's illegal too